# XHTML Mark-up Validation error

Tags: html

I'm trying to validate my XHTML but I'm getting two errors firstly **"end tag for "li" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified"** and **" document type does not allow element "ul" here; assuming missing "li" start-tag."**

How do I solve this whilst still keeping the bottom two links a sub list of the first one? Thanks

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#div_into">Introduction</a></li>
<li ><a href="#div_hist">History</a></li>
<li><a href="#div_national">National Flags</a></li>
<li><a href="#div_signalFlags">International Maritime Signal Flags</a></li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#div_letters">International Maritime Signal: Letters</a></li>
        <li><a href="#div_numbers">International Maritime Signal: Numbers</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Maybe the  _...Flags</a></li>_ tag is closed to early. It should be closed after the second </ul>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#div_into">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#div_hist">History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#div_national">National Flags</a></li>
    <li><a href="#div_signalFlags">International Maritime Signal Flags</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#div_letters">International Maritime Signal: Letters</a></li>
            <li><a href="#div_numbers">International Maritime Signal: Numbers</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Only a `<li>` element can be a child of a `<ul>`. You have a starting list after the `International Maritime Signal Flags` item which should be within that item, not after it.